# Транскрипция фразы

Tags: транскрипция

Очень нужна транскрипция фразы: Она многое ясно видела, многое её серьезно занимало. Помогите пожалуйста, 10 уже пересдача зачета.Спасибо

Comment: А на зачете принимают домашние заготовки? Интересно, в каком учебном заведении зачет? В школе сейчас эта транскрипция с пятого класса. Надеюсь, Вы не учителем собираетесь работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она многое ясно видела, многое её серьезно занимало

[Λна многъjь jаснъ в'ид'ьлъ /  многъjь jи(с призвуком е)jо  с'и(с призв.е)р'jознъ зън'ималъ//]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!